# Options not cleared from previous call jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, variables

I've made this little plugin to show Twitter style alerts:

```
        jQuery.fn.myAlert = function (options) {
            var defaults = {
                message: false,
            class: 'normal',
                timer: 500,
                delay: 3000,
            };
            var options = $.extend(defaults, options);
            if (!options.message || options.message == '') {
                return false;
            }
            $('body').append('<div id="alert_notification" class="'+options.class+'"><div id="alert_message">' + options.message + '</div></div>')
            $('#alert_notification').slideToggle(options.timer).delay(options.delay).slideToggle(options.timer);
        return;
        }
```

The problem is: first time it works great, but when I call again in the same page, the values are set from previous call.

Any ideas how to make it work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My guess is that the `slideToggle()` isn't showing the `<div>` you are intending it to show because jQuery isn't appending new `<div>`s that don't have unique IDs. You should probably remove the originally appended `<div>`s from the page before appending the new ones. Or, make jQuery replace the existing ones.

```
$('#alert_notification').remove();
$('body').append(...);
```

In addition, `class` is a reserved word in JavaScript. I would change your `defaults` to:

```
var defaults = {
    message: false,
    'class': 'normal',
    timer: 500,
    delay: 3000,
};
```

And then access it with `options['class']` instead of `options.class`, or pick a different name for the `class` property.

Comment: Thank you, as you can see, I'm begginer, but soon I'll be a ninja xD